# Modifying UIButton created in IB not correct size on iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, ios

I am trying to programatically add a gradient layer to a UIButton which was initially created in Interface Builder. I added the new gradient layer in the viewDidLoad method of the ViewController. I have no issues in adding the gradient.

```
    CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradientLayer.frame = self.btn.layer.bounds;

    gradientLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor topGradient] CGColor],(id)[[UIColor bottomGradient] CGColor], nil];
   [self.btn.layer insertSublayer:gradientLayer atIndex:0];
```

The problem is : I am getting the frame from the button created in IB which was laid out with iPhone 4 screen size. All the resize masks are set and work properly and the button on screen on the iPhone 5 simulator is the correct size.

However the gradient applied, only partially fills the button as it is applied to the original frame. How do I get the frame AFTER it has had the autoresizemasks applied to it?

Thanks

Comment: Try This [gradientLayer setFrame:self.btn.bounds]; in place of gradientLayer.frame = self.btn.layer.bounds;

Comment: Do u get correct Frame when u do this NSLog(@"%d %d",btn.frame.size.width,btn.frame.size.height); ?

Comment: Again that gives the old frame size from IB

Comment: viewWillAppear - at this stage the button has the right frame size but I would rather not put all that drawing of gradients in this method as  it always called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

had to add this in viewWillAppear